# Best practice two graphics cards

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors

I think about getting a second graphics card.
I own a 2080 RTX TI that I use to render 3d stuff and gameing.

When I render a huge 3d scene that takes several hours, the computer is buys and of course its not possible to play games while the scene is rendering.

So I tought about buying a second 2080RTX TI.
Then I can play games on one card and use the other to render stuff.

Before I buy that rather expensice setup I have to know two things:
1. Is it possible to tell Windows which graphics card should be used for a specific task? Like use this graphics card for games and this for everything other.

2. Does it matter on wich graphics card I attach my monitor?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible on Windows to assign GPU affinity to a program,as follows:

- Run *Settings > Display*
- Click *Graphics settings*
- Select *Classic app* in the "Choose an app to set preference" drop menu,
  and click *Browse*
- Select the `.exe` file and click *Add*
- Once the application is listed, click it and select *Options*
- Select one of System default, Power saving, or High performance and click *Save*

[image]

For more information see the article
[How to Set Preferred GPU for Apps in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/103965-set-preferred-gpu-apps-windows-10-a.html).